# Want to retrieve academic result data from the other site to my site

Tags: php

I am creating a academic/community site in Joomla . One of my site requirement is to obtain the  result from the official college site . I will be creating a module on my site  which will have college id as input and on submission it will show the result obtained from the official website .

I am finding it difficult to pass the data from one site to other . The official website is using Post method for college id input .

Please help me with detailed approach with programming code sample . It will be highly appreciated .
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will need something like PHP CURL for your problem. Your code could be something like:

```
<?php 

$url = "http://www.collegesite.com"; 
$ch = curl_init();    // initialize curl handle 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); // set url to post to 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);// allow redirects 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3); // times out after 4s 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // set POST method 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "collegid=40"); // add POST fields 
$result = curl_exec($ch); // run the whole process 
curl_close($ch);  
echo $result; 
?>
```

Then you can use regex to get whatever data you want from $result. You may want to read the net up a bit about CURL.

Comment: Thanks for your quick support. Please don't mind my ignorance of php programming . can anybody write the code for this page http://results.vtu.ac.in/ . input is 1kn04cs066

Comment: Sorry, I cannot. Please pickup any PHP book to understand the basics or even W3Schools would do.